# AngularJs Filter hide options if no products

Tags: angularjs

I have found this filter and I'm trying to edit it so that you select an option then it greys out the other option For example if you select (vegetable) you can only select (Orange).

I'm not sure how to out it into code but I the logic for it. On the dynamicFilter function need to update the filter options count and if its less then 1 needs to add a class or something.

Here is my code pen any help would be awesome.

https://codepen.io/natedog213/pen/mwPxmy

```
<div ng-app='angularDemo' ng-cloak>
    <md-toolbar layout-padding>
    <h2>Filtering with Angular Filters</h2>
    </md-toolbar>
    <div layout="row" ng-controller="angularController as ctrl">

        <div flex="20" class="sidebar" layout-padding>

            <!-- Repeat the filter types and there options -->
            <div ng-repeat="filter in Filters">
                <h3>{{filter.name}}</h3>
                <ul class="filteroptions">
                    <li ng-repeat="option in filter.options">
                        <input id="{{option.value}}" class="filter_option" type="checkbox" data-name="{{option.value}}" ng-model="option.IsIncluded" ng-checked="option.IsIncluded">
                        <label for="{{option.value}}">{{option.value}}</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div flex="50" layout="row">
            <div flex ng-repeat="product in products | dynamicFilter:Filters:this" class="product">
                {{product.name}}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add condition according to your filter like as ng-show="(products | unique:'price').length > 0"

Try this

```
<div class="side_menu">

    <h2>Product Types</h2>

    <div data-ng-repeat="product in products | unique:'type'">
        <input id="{{product.type}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="search.type" ng-true-value="'{{product.type}}'" ng-false-value='' /><label for="{{ product.type }}">{{ product.type }} </label>
    </div>


    <br>
    <h2 ng-show="(products | unique:'price').length > 0">Product Price</h2>
    <div data-ng-repeat="product in products | unique:'price'">
        <input id="{{product.price}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="search.type1" ng-true-value="'{{product.price}}'" ng-false-value='' /><label for="{{ product.price }}">{{ product.price }} </label>
    </div>


</div>
```